# Wordnet Synonyms not returning all values nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to get all the synonyms or similar words using nltk's wordnet but it is not returning.

I am doing:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('swap')
[Synset('barter.n.01'), Synset('trade.v.04'), Synset('swap.v.02')]
```

I also tried doing (from one of the stackoverflow page):

```
>>> for ss in wn.synsets('swap'):
    for sim in ss.similar_tos():
        print('     {}'.format(sim))
```

But I am not getting all the synonyms. I do not want to add synonyms to the wordnet.
I am expecting it to return exchange,interchange, substitute etc.

How to achieve this?

Thanks

Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get synonyms using `wordnet`, simply do this:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> for synset in wn.synsets('swap'):
    for lemma in synset.lemmas():
        print lemma.name(),

barter swap swop trade trade swap swop switch swap  # note the overlap between the synsets
```

To obtain some of the words you mentioned, you may have to include hypernyms as well:

```
>>> for synset in wn.synsets('swap'):
    for hypernym in synset.hypernyms():
        for ss in hypernym.lemmas():  # now you need to iterate through each synset returned by synset.hypernyms()
            print ss.name(),

exchange interchange exchange change interchange travel go move locomote  # again, some overlap
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, exactly what I was looking for. I concatenated both as per my need..Thanks

Comment: @user3089927 Great! I'm glad to hear it helped.